# Scan an image for certain colors, convert to an integer array

Tags: image, arduino

So I recently obtained an 8x8 bi-color LED array for my arduino kit, and I want to be able to read an image file for certain RGB values at certain coordinates, to create a 2d int array, with the ints corresponding to certain RGB values. for instance, since my array can display 3 different colors, i could define three different RGB values to read from the image in the code. then i'd have it read the image, make a 2d int array by the dimensions of the image, store ints 1-3 in the array where the corresponding RGB values were found.

i was going to try and find a C library for it but I think that arduino is a separate language, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I did similar stuff for my Blinkenlight Experiments. Especially for the POV experiments. You might want to have a look at my Python code for converting images to Arduino Programms here: http://blog.blinkenlight.net/experiments/basic-effects/pov-generator/.

Another easy way to convert images to C code is to use ["The Gimp".](http://www.gimp.org/) The Gimp supports "save as C source code" and "save as C header".

Just for completeness: Arduino is not a separate language. Arduino is C++ with some IDE preprocessing that tries to hide the fact that you actually code C++.

Comment: I think I may have said this wrong. Is there any way I can get the size of an image or the RGB value at a certain pixel in an image? I don't get how the python program works, either. edit: also, could i use a c++ image library in my arduino code?

Comment: The first question is how you would get the image into the Arduino. Usually you will have your images in a filesystem. However the Arduino does not have a filesystem. Thus you need to store them in flash memory somehow. This is what my answer is about.